# Bounding above the rank of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I heard about a theorem that states $\text{rank}(X) \leq r$ if the determinant of every $r \times r$ minor of $X$ is zero. Does anyone know of a reference for this theorem or a proof of it?

Comment: The rank of a matrix can be equivalently defined as the dimension of the largest minor whose determinant is not zero. Hence, if the determinant of every $r\times r$ minor of $X$ is zero, the rank of $X$ cannot be larger than r

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_%28linear_algebra%29#Alternative_definitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can prove the contrapositive, i.e. that a matrix of rank $r$ will have an $r \times r$ submatrix which is nonsingular.

Quite simply: an $n \times n$  matrix of rank $r$ has $r$ linearly independent columns. Form a matrix out of these columns. Since row rank = column rank, the matrix consisting of these columns have $r$ linearly independent rows. There is your $r \times r$ submatrix.